# UITabBar delegate's method not getting called when item is selected from a "More" view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I have overwritten the tab bar controller and tab bar item classes in my code. In the tab bar controller's delegate method `- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item` I added some code to set initial values to the selected item's properties.

The method is called when I select the item from a tabbar. 
But, since I added some more buttons to the bar, I got the `...` button, with "More" - that shows up a list of hidden items when is pressed.

The problem is, when I select one of those "hidden" items, it loads up the view controller that should be loaded, but doesn't call the `didSelectItem` method in my class, so the initial property setting made there is not done.

Should I implement some other methods in there? Or am I doing it the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this method is not called for view controllers in "More". You could try to do your configuration in

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```